# CSV writing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following sample is my result and number of rows are around 1 million.

```
1 MSH12278732 HSH07392960 956
2 MSH12278732 WSH88257552 940
3 MSH12278732 CSH71109822 923
4 MSH12278732 FSH16284786 920
5 MSH12278732 sucharu_85 917
6 MSH12278732 TSH39376759 911
7 MSH12278732 MSH44112791 908
8 ----   ----- ---
```

and so on ....

My program is:

```
with open ("result3.csv",'wb') as outcsv:
   writer=csv.writer(outcsv)
   wr=csv.writer(outcsv,dialect='excel')
```

And result came as

```
wr.writerow(z)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: You should read - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide a minimal , complete, and verifiable example that reproduces your issue, the code you provided right now is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message -

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

I believe the issue would be because of line -

```
with open ("result3.csv",'wb') as outcsv:
```

You should open the file in `w` mode, not binary mode (`'wb'`). Example -

```
with open ("result3.csv",'w') as outcsv:
```

---

I can reproduce similar error using -

```
>>> with open ("result3.csv",'wb') as outcsv:
...    wr=csv.writer(outcsv,dialect='excel')
...    wr.writerow(['1','2','3'])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: but data is saving in alternate row instead of continuous row.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by alternate rows ? And also show how 'z' is calculated .

Answer (score 1):

If your source data is in a text file, then the following should work as needed:

```
import csv

with open("input.txt", "r") as f_input, open ("result3.csv",'wb') as f_output:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output, dialect='excel') 
    csv_writer.writerows(csv_reader)
```

If you already have the data as one big lump as shown above, you can adapt it as follows:

```
import csv, StringIO

data = """1 MSH12278732 HSH07392960 956
2 MSH12278732 WSH88257552 940
3 MSH12278732 CSH71109822 923
4 MSH12278732 FSH16284786 920
5 MSH12278732 sucharu_85 917
6 MSH12278732 TSH39376759 911
7 MSH12278732 MSH44112791 908"""

with open ("result3.csv",'wb') as f_output:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), delimiter=' ')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f_output, dialect='excel') 
    csv_writer.writerows(csv_reader)
```

Both of these would give you the following output which can be loaded into Excel:

```
1,MSH12278732,HSH07392960,956
2,MSH12278732,WSH88257552,940
3,MSH12278732,CSH71109822,923
4,MSH12278732,FSH16284786,920
5,MSH12278732,sucharu_85,917
6,MSH12278732,TSH39376759,911
7,MSH12278732,MSH44112791,908
```

Note, if you are using Python 3, you will get the error `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. You need to change your `open` statement as follows:

```
with open("result3.csv",'w', newline='') as f_output:
    ....
```

Comment: You can shorten to `csv_writer.writerows( csv_reader)`

Comment: Indeed, have updated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough details to help us help you debug your stuff, but at least I can tell you :

```
writer=csv.writer(outcsv)
wr=csv.writer(outcsv,dialect='excel')
```

this is likely to fail. You're using two csv writers on the same file, I'm not sure if `csv.writer()` has been designed to cope with that kind of situation